# ¿Por qué un color fijo cambia a oscuro cuando está activado el modo oscuro en Android?

Tags: java

Tengo un tema diseñado en Android:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue"/>
</layer-list>
```

El problema aparece cuando activo el modo oscuro en Android, el color azul se vuelve un poco más oscuro que el indicado (#0000ff). En esta pregunta, al usuario le pasa lo mismo, pero no se encuentra una solución: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68207951/how-to-make-background-color-fixed-for-dark-mode-and-light-mode-of-the-device

¿Por qué sucede esto y cuál es la solución?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar crear un nuevo archivo de recurso de colores pero para la versión de night

```
colors-night.xml
```

Y agregar exactamente el mismo nombre del color y el mismo valor HEX.

Comment: Lo he creado, pero no se si es un problema de Xiaomi, porque el problema persiste

Comment: Parece ser problema de Xiaomi (porque también lo probé), lo probé en los emuladores del android studio, y ahí conservan las tonalidades.

Comment: Sí, posiblemente es eso